# In Ruby, what does a hash followed by rectangular brackets do?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, what does a hash followed by rectangular brackets do? example ->

```
quantity = { :buy => 1, :sell => -1}[action.to_sym]
```

Answer (score 6):

It's equivalent to

```
hash = { :buy => 1, :sell => -1}
quantity = hash[action.to_sym]
```

It works also for arrays or string:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'][1]    # -> 'b'
'abc'[1]              # ->  'b'
```

Comment: You are just rewriting the original oneliner in two lines, which does not make any difference, and are not answering the question.

Comment: I think Baldrick is assuming Ash does know, since he calls it a hash, what [] does in the usual case, and is just not picking up on the inline-ness.

Answer (score 2):

It returns the value (what is on the right side of the arrow `=>`) that corresponds to the key (what is on the left side of the arrow) given in `[]`. For example, if `action.to_sym` turns out to be `:buy`, then `quantity` will be `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Any peace of code in ruby has object result. So `{ :buy => 1, :sell => -1}` gives hash object with keys and values. Hash it is the data structure that has keys and values. You can get value by key through brackets like this: `hash[:buy]`. So you have hash object here after `{ :buy => 1, :sell => -1}` and you gets value by key `action.to_sym`